# Screen video (screencast) recording on Linux

Tags: linux, gtk, x11, screencast

I was trying to record video of all the monitors or a selection, so was wondering what to use for Linux.

The thoughts that came to mind were screenshot the screen a bunch but this probably isnt the right way to go about it.

I looked at the Cairo docs but can't find anyhting. On Windows I found DirectShow and OSX I found AVFoundation.

edit:
i just came across something: `XvGetVideo` would this be an option?

Comment: Are you trying to record a screencast or programmatically record video from the screen?

Comment: Thanks @ptomato for the attn :) Im trying to basically do as if i was taking multiple screenshots every 25ms and then combine them togather. But I was thinking there had to be a better more recommended way then doing the so many screenshots every few ms. So record screencast, basically whatever shows in screenshot, so if htere is a video on screen, it should be visible no?

Comment: I'm asking what is your goal with this. To record a screencast of yourself performing actions on the desktop which you can then publish? Or to write a program which will record video from the screen for other people?

Comment: Ah yep screencast which i can then make into gif or other format to upload to youtube or twittter, i do a lot of tutorails and find that screencasts help a lot.

Comment: No need to program it yourself. Take a look at [this question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/4428/how-to-create-a-screencast) for screencast software recommendations.

Comment: Thanks very much @ptomato but i really want to make one myself as there is so much learning that happens through that. I teach people a lot of stuff and these projects help me a ton! I want to hook up some custom things too like upload to youtube/twitter various cloud services. Just something from a firefox addon scope :) Ill try to see if i can get my hands on the sources for those apps but if you or anyone have any hints please share

Comment: OK, so your goal was actually the second option: to write a program which will record video from the screen. Take a look at the sources for the screencast apps, or look at how gnome-shell does it: https://git.gnome.org/browse/gnome-shell/tree/src/shell-recorder.c, it basically grabs frames and feeds them into a gstreamer encoding pipeline.

Comment: Ah excuse that please. Thanks so much I'll look into that and update you with the code i write :)

Answer (score 1):

You can check out [ffscreencast](https://github.com/cytopia/ffscreencast) with the `--dry` parameter which will show you the commands that would be issued. Looks nice for learning.

Did it under linux and it showed me it was using [x11Grab](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-devices.html#x11grab)